# JxBrowser: what does url in cookie mean?

Tags: java, cookies, jxbrowser

I want to backup cookie into file, and when needed, I will restore it via

```
boolean setCookie(java.lang.String url,
                  java.lang.String name,
                  java.lang.String value,
                  java.lang.String domain,
                  java.lang.String path,
                  long expirationTimeInMicroseconds,
                  boolean secure,
                  boolean httpOnly)
```

but when backup, there is no **url** in cookie:

```
public interface Cookie {
    String getName();

    String getValue();

    String getDomain();

    String getPath();

    long getCreationTime();

    long getUnixCreationTime();

    long getExpirationTime();

    long getUnixExpirationTime();

    boolean isSecure();

    boolean isHTTPOnly();

    boolean isSession();
}
```

Now I just combine **http://** + **domain** without prefix dot. Is that right? And I wonder why need the url field when setCookie?

Answer (score 0):

Url is not part of the cookie. You need url parameter to link cookie with a site for which that cookie is created.

More details on how cookies work in JxBrowser you can find by the next link: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/folders/9000074855

Comment: I know that, my question is: if I want to restore cookie from what I saved, how url should be?

Comment: You will need the same URL you used to save cookie

Comment: I use getAllCookies() to get all cookies from all URL, how can I know URL for each cooke?

Comment: There is no clear way to know URL for each cookie. Combining http:// + domain without prefix dot is not the reliable way as a domain may be different from cookie's URL domain.